# How to update Database before session Destroyed in spring security for java class?

Tags: spring, session, spring-security

I am working on one task in which I need to update logout time in login-logout log table. I have configure automatic session expire time. In case of logout its updating Database but in case of automatic logout by session expired its not updating database. I tried lots of things like keepSessionAlive(). I also tried onApplicationEvent on sessionDestroyed but nothing is working to me.

here is the SessionListener.java

```
@Component
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener, 
ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent> {

@Autowired
LoginLogoutLogService loginLogoutLogService;

@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(1 * 60);
}

@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    HttpSession session = event.getSession();
    LoginDetailsBean loginDetailsBean = (LoginDetailsBean) session.getAttribute("loginUser");
    String loginTimeStamp = DateHelper.dateToString(loginDetailsBean.getLoginTimestamp());
    String logoutTimeStamp = DateHelper.dateToString(new Date());
    String loginId = loginDetailsBean.getLoginUserid();
    // updateLogoutTime(logoutTimeStamp,loginId,loginTimeStamp); 
    System.out.printf("Session ID %s destroyed at %s%n", event.getSession().getId(), new Date());
}

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDestroyedEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Bofore Destroyed....");
}

public void updateLogoutTime(String logoutTimeStamp, String loginId, String loginTimeStemp) {
    loginLogoutLogService.updateLogoutTime(logoutTimeStamp, loginId, loginTimeStemp);
    System.out.println("Database update successfully...");
}
```

}

So please tell me how can I update DB before sessionDestroyed in spring security.

Answer (score 1):

This code will work.....

```
package com.auction.web.security;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionDestroyedEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.auction.commons.util.DateHelper;
import com.auction.model.bean.LoginDetailsBean;
import com.auction.service.LoginLogoutLogService;

@Component 
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener, ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent>,Serializable,HttpSessionBindingListener{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Autowired
LoginLogoutLogService loginLogoutLogService;

@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(1 * 60);
}

@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    /*HttpSession session = event.getSession();
    LoginDetailsBean loginDetailsBean = (LoginDetailsBean) session.getAttribute("loginUser");
    String loginTimeStamp = DateHelper.dateToString(loginDetailsBean.getLoginTimestamp());
    String logoutTimeStamp = DateHelper.dateToString(new Date());
    String loginId = loginDetailsBean.getLoginUserid();*/
    // updateLogoutTime(logoutTimeStamp,loginId,loginTimeStamp); 
    System.out.printf("Session ID %s destroyed at %s%n", event.getSession().getId(), new Date());
}

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDestroyedEvent event) {

    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) event.getSource();
    LoginDetailsBean loginDetailsBean = (LoginDetailsBean) session.getAttribute("loginUser");
    String loginTimeStamp = DateHelper.dateToString(loginDetailsBean.getLoginTimestamp());
    String logoutTimeStamp = DateHelper.dateToString(new Date());
    String loginId = loginDetailsBean.getLoginUserid();
    updateLogoutTime(logoutTimeStamp,loginId,loginTimeStamp);
}

public void updateLogoutTime(String logoutTimeStamp, String loginId, String loginTimeStemp) {
    loginLogoutLogService.updateLogoutTime(logoutTimeStamp, loginId, loginTimeStemp);
    System.out.println("Database update successfully...");
}

@Override
public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
    System.out.println("valueBound:" + event.getName() + " session:" + event.getSession().getId() );

}

public void registerSession() {
   // FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put( "sessionBindingListener", this  );
    System.out.println( "registered sessionBindingListener"  );
}

@Override
public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
   System.out.println("valueUnBound:" + event.getName() + " session:" + event.getSession().getId() );
           // add you unlock code here:
   // clearLocksForSession( event.getSession().getId() );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This can be a possibility where in you can use HttpSessionBindingListener and register a session which holds a lock by calling registerSession

```
public class HttpSessionLock implements Serializable,HttpSessionBindingListener {
    public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        log.info("valueBound:" + event.getName() + " session:" + event.getSession().getId() );

    }

public void registerSession() {        
    log.info( "registered sessionBindingListener"  );
}

public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
    log.info("valueUnBound:" + event.getName() + " session:" + event.getSession().getId() );

    log.info( "unregistering sessionBindingListener"  );
    // coding for db
    }
    }
```

Comment: when you say session destroyed does it mean logout or session timing out